# Getting data from my join table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a join table which takes the id from my respondents table `respondant_id` and the id from my teams table `table_id`.

The output is fine when I SELECT from that table so I get back the respondants ID married up with the teams ID.

I am wanting to show the respondents name from `respondant_data` and the team name from `teams` by using the values output from the join table.

I have attempted this here but I keep getting 0 results.

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
respondant_data.respondant_id, teams.team_id
FROM 
    respondant_data
INNER JOIN 
    teams 
ON
    respondant_data.respondant_id = teams.team_id
WHERE 
    respondant_teams.team_id= 5";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$i = 1;

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $i++ . ' ';
        echo 'user_id: ' . $row["respondant_id"] . ', ';
        echo 'team_id: ' . $row["team_id"];
        echo '<br>';        
    }
} else{
    echo 'no results';
}
```

So I want my output to be like 'John Smith', 'Central Team'

Comment: at one place you have used teams(line 7,9), and at one place you have used respondant_teams(line 11). use proper table names.

Comment: probably you're joining tables on the WRONG keys.... if respondant_data has a foreign key like team_id... then JOIN could be on: respondant_data.team_id = teams.team_id.... where team_id on the respondant_data table is a foreign key pointing to the teams table...

Comment: Iv got myself all confused :( so yeah I just wanna join up my middle table which has the respondant_id and team_id and out output the name of the dude and the name of the team they belong too...

Comment: @kaushikkaran I have a table called respondant_teams which is a collaboration of the respondents and teams, isn't that fairly logical? It takes the repondant_id and team_id and into the two columns.

Comment: @barudo I originally had a column with multiple string values but I was warned not to do that and create a table that takes two values but its just made it even more confusing.

Comment: @Dan in your query, you are joining respondant_data and teams. But in where clause you are using a third table(respondant_teams) which is not logical

Comment: @kaushikkaran I thought by doing that I could could select the Id from my respondent table, the id from the teams table and make a reference in the third table. Essentially I want to get the two IDs from the third table, check the respondent_data id and give me the persons name and the same with the teams table, look it up by and give me the team name

Comment: @kaushikkaran is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query.

```
SELECT 
    resp_data.respondant_id, teams.team_id
FROM
    respondant_data resp_data,
    teams,
    respondant_teams resp_teams
WHERE
    resp_data.respondant_id = teams.team_id
        and resp_teams.team_id = teams.team_id
        and resp_teams.team_id = 5
```